# Raster data summarized in different vector polygons

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, noise, summary

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.9.2 and I have a raster dataset of noise pollution across England with different noise levels. I also have the LSOA vector shp file. I want to get the average noise level per LSOA.

Which tool can I use to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Zonal statistics](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/spatial-analyst/how-zonal-statistics-works.htm#:%7E:text=A%20zonal%20statistics%20operation%20is,and%20Zonal%20Statistics%20as%20Table.):

> A zonal statistics operation is one that calculates statistics on cell
> values of a raster (a value raster) within the zones defined by
> another dataset.